# define qtimer global or local? and the pros and cons?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

When programming with Qt timers, we can define timers globally, and let one slot to exec all the other timer related operations (like callbacks); we can also define timers for each related class locally.

So, what's the pros and cons?

Comment: That is more like what is your requirement and how you want to design it.
You can go for any approach which will suit your current requirement.

Comment: Definitely yes, and that's why I want to find the pros and cons. like the efficiency or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using a global `QTimer` is that it will trigger all connected slots in a row. After a while, multiple QTimers may end up desynchronizing and they could timeout asynchronously even if they were started synchronously with the same interval. See [Is QTimer smart enough to resynchronize itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34543745/3336423)

CPU load also could make one `QTimer` timeout too late, so if you have many supposed to be synchronous, they could timeout asynchronously if system is loaded, having a single `QTimer` could avoid that (once it timeouts, all connected slots will be fired in a row with no interruption).

Now, the obvious advantage of having multiple QTimers is that they can be configured with different timeout intervals. And they could also be encapsulated in reusable standalone modules or classes (would be harder to reuse modules or classes in another project if they don't have their own `QTimer` and request the developer to declare and setup a global one, but, a singleton pattern could help with that).