# Is QTimer smart enough to resynchronize itself

Tags: qt, qtimer

Let's say we start a `QTimer` with a 100ms interval at t0.

Let's say first timeout occurs at t0+100ms. Fine.

Let's say that, due to huge CPU load and/or lots of events having to be handled by the event loop, second timeout occurs at t0+230ms.

Let's say CPU is back to normal load. Is their any chance that third timeout could occur at t0+300ms (`QTimer` object realising it was late and trying to correct that by resynchronizing itself), or will it most likely timeout at t0+330ms?

Answer (score 0):

Per [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) documentation :

> All timer types may time out later than expected if the system is busy or unable to provide the requested accuracy. In such a case of timeout overrun, Qt will emit activated() only once, even if multiple timeouts have expired, and then will resume the original interval.

I'm not sure I understand this correctly but, apparently, it won't resynchronize itself and third timeout will occur at t0+330ms.